# Trouble splitting xml file evenly

Tags: java, xml

I'm am having trouble splitting a large xml file into even smaller files based on element count. I found some code from a previous question that worked for splitting by a tag but can't seem to split the file by the element count. One file will be created after I set the element count to 100. If I increase the count the size of the file increases but multiple files are not created to account for the entire original xml file.

```
public class Splitter {
    private static void appendStuff(String content, File file) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) throws Exception {
        String prefix = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + "\n";
        String suffix = "\n</RCStatus>\n";
        int count = 0;
        try {

            int i = 1;
            XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("Carriers.xml"));
            xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to statements element

            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();

            File file = new File("\\Desktop\\xml\\" + "status" + i + ".xml");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            appendStuff("<RCStatus>", file);
            while (xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                count++;
                t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StreamResult(fos));
                if(count == 100) {
                    count = 0;
                    i++;
                    appendStuff("</RCStatus>", file);
                    fos.close();
                    file = new File("\\Desktop\\xml\\" + "status" + i +".xml");
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                    appendStuff("<RCStatus>", file);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<RCStatus> 
  <H> 
    <T>a</T> 
      <A>E</A> 
      <V>12</V> 
      <R>S</R> 
   </H> 
   <C> 
    <Co>I</Co> 
    <RM>5</RM> 
    <Ta/> 
    <MC>xx</MC> 
    <DOT>1</DOT> 
    <A1>xxx</1> 
    <A2 /> 
    <Cy>x</Cy> 
    <St>I</St> 
    <Z>x</Z> 
    <Ct>xx</Ct> 
    <T>VP</T> 
    <P>x</P> 
    <F>xxx</F> 
    <E>x</E> 
    <Pa /> 
    <PaA /> 
    <PaC /> 
    <PaSt /> 
    <PaZ /> 
    <Cl = /> 
    <iISN /> 
    <iISS /> 
    <Ds /> 
    <Pay2 /> 
    <PC /> 
    <C>U</C> 
    <IF /> 
   </C> 
</RCStatus>
```

Comment: Can you post a (small) sample xml file to see it's structure?

Comment: @aka-one I have edited the question to include a snippet of code

Comment: I now see that the xml file is split into a smaller file that contains the first 1,000 lines repeated 4 times instead of taking in the first 4,000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

XML files are flat files that represent a tree structure.

The tree structure doesn't need to be balanced in an XML file, so the primary question is "what's an even split of an unbalanced tree"?

To illustrate, your tree has a top level elemant of `RCStatus` and two sibling elements of `H` and `C`.  If I split the tree evenly among siblings, I will get one file that is smaller (the one containing the `H` sibling) and one file that is larger (the one containing the `C` sibling).

Perhaps that is what is wanted.  Perhaps not.

A second approach would be to "contain the same number of leaf elements" then the files will only be approximately equal, as the structure of the parent elements for the two files is likely to differ, leading to variations in size.

So, I think you need to better express what you mean by split, as cutting an XML file literally in half would make it an invalid non-XML file.

Comment: Well I have a large xml file that I want to split based on the tag RCStatus. I say evenly because I'm attempting to do each file contains 100 elements.